# Generate a scoped model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

I need to generate unique order numbers per account.  Each account can have order 1000 BUT order 1000 can not exist in the same account.

```
@account1 = Account.first
@account1.orders.create(:price => 1.20) # order 1000 auto generated, next will be 1001
```

account1 then can not have two orders with a number 1000 but other accounts can.

I'm struggling with the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add validation, e.g. add the following to your order model:

```
validates :order_no, :uniqueness => { :scope => :account, :message => "Try again saving, a deadlock might have occurred!"}
```

to make sure, the ids are actually unique and no deadlock occurred. Then add the following validation:

```
before_validation :generate_and_set_uniq_order_no
```

with

```
def generate_and_set_uniq_order_no
  # insert Amit's solution here, or anything else (e.g. sorting/unifying/incrementing)
end
```

to really GET a uniq id.

Comment: Accepting as the answer because the :scope bit was important to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Table Sequencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing) where a table would hold last id for each account. The structure of your table would like

```
ACCOUNT_ID  CURRENT_ID
3283    1000
5078    1000
9000       1
```

Each time you create order increment, use it as order id and update CURRENT_ID for the account .

Note the issue with this solution is [Concurrency and Deadlock](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Concurrency_and_Deadlocks)